# How to edit this Angular Material Chips CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I have a Angular App. My HTML look like this so far:

```
body
 - <div side-nav right-aligned>
  - <div #configArea>
   -- Here we have 3 fields
```

Inside this config are I have 3 fields that are , from Angular Material.
The thing is, I need one of them to use [Angular Material Chips](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview).

So, I've followed the tutorials, but this 3 fields have the exactly same CSS, and I need to modify a single CSS to make it work but this div **does not exist in my code, just in browser**. To make it work I must set the height to "auto", but nothing works so far.

[This is the class CSS I have to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNjgQ.png)

[This is what happens due height bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh214.png)

Using Angular 4.4.2

Comment: what css properties did you add?

Comment: share your code , better a demo on stackblitz.com

Comment: Css works fine on dynamically created elements as well. if `.mat-form-field-infix` doesn't work (try in your devtools first), maybe you have a typo in your selector? If you only want the third element you could try a n:th-selector (or better add a different css-class for that item). Troubleshooting pictures of code is just hopeless.

Comment: yes @ippi is right, css works fine on the dynamically created elements. If in angular component's css file, you might have to use :host >>> selector. And add a different css-class for each, so you can style easily.

Comment: Please, for such issues, you better create a small demo on StackBlitz as @ShashankVivek mentioned. In this way, we can better localize what it exactly going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekKumar your answer gave me an idea, and I solved the problem.

Comment: thank you, its good to see that it helped. Can you please upvote that comment as it was helpful. Thank you, Happy helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this by using **::ng-deep** tag ,selecting exactly the div I wanted.

Something like this worked for me:

> yes @ippi is right, css works fine on the dynamically created elements. If in angular component's css file, you might have to use :host >>> selector. And add a different css-class for each, so you can style easily. – Abhishek Kumar